# Contiki: Address of a thread having unrecognized value

Tags: debugging, arm, memory-address, contiki

I am trying to port Contiki to LPC1347, just a basic LED blinking program for now. It compiles without any errors but i get a hard fault when i try to run it. On debugging i understood that the hello_world_process thread has an address of 0x636F6C42 (ASCII value considering it to be little endian is Bloc!) which is unrecognized by the mcu. I am using the default initialing libraries of Contiki, i do not understand if there is something wrong with the initialization or any other reason (perhaps something wrong with my linker script or makefile)? Can somebody please help me debug this.

Here is my project's [link](https://github.com/kabirbansod/Contiki-lpc1347).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was because i was using printf without providing libraries/functions to handle dynamic memory allocation. The program works fine if i do not use printf!